# TortiouseSVN connection to github.com using SSH

Tags: github, ssh, tortoisesvn

I am trying to access my github.com repository using TortiouseSVN via SSH.  Using HTTPS works fine, but the repository has grown so large that I am getting timeouts when doing updates.

I have created the private/public key using git bash, registered it to github, and converted it to a private/public putty key.

I added the key to Pageant Key list for automatic login.

Putty configuration:
Session Category:
host name: git@github.com
port: 22  (SSH)
SessionName: github

Connection/Data Category:
Auto-login username: 
SSH/Auth
Private key file is the putty converted .ppk file

TortoiseSVN settings:
Network:
SSH Client:
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe"

Connecting via putty connects and gives me this:
Using username "git".
Authenticating with public key "" from agent
Server refused to allocate pty
Hi !  You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
However, when try to "SVN Checkout" using TortiouseSVN in a folder. I get the following:
URL Format:       svn+ssh:///repo/repo.git/
URL:              svn+ssh://github/myname/online.git/

Here are the results:
Tortiouse SVN:
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at url
Error: svn+ssh://github//myname/online.git/
Error: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the
Error: [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
Error: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Putty Log:
Event Log: Looking up host "github.com" for SSH connection
Event Log: Connecting to 140.82.113.3 port 22
Event Log: We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTYTortoisePlink_Release_0.72
Event Log: Remote version: SSH-2.0-babeld-78794f53
Event Log: Using SSH protocol version 2
Event Log: No GSSAPI security context available
Event Log: Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (unaccelerated)
Event Log: Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
Event Log: Host key fingerprint is:
Event Log: ssh-rsa 2048 
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) outbound MAC algorithm
Event Log: Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
Event Log: Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) inbound MAC algorithm
Event Log: Reading key file "path to .ppk file"
Event Log: Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Event Log: Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Event Log: Pageant key #0 matches configured key file
Event Log: Trying Pageant key #0
Event Log: Sending Pageant's response
Event Log: Access granted
Event Log: Opening main session channel
Event Log: Opened main channel
Incoming packet #0x8, type 99 / 0x63 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS)
00000000  00 00 01 00                                      ....
Incoming packet #0x9, type 95 / 0x5f (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA)
00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 be 49 6e 76 61  **............Inva**
00000010  6c 69 64 20 63 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 3a 20 27 73 76  **lid command: 'sv**
00000020  6e 73 65 72 76 65 20 2d 74 27 0a 20 20 59 6f 75  **nserve -t'.  You**
00000030  20 61 70 70 65 61 72 20 74 6f 20 62 65 20 75 73  **appear to be us**
00000040  69 6e 67 20 73 73 68 20 74 6f 20 63 6c 6f 6e 65  **ing ssh to clone**
00000050  20 61 20 67 69 74 3a 2f 2f 20 55 52 4c 2e 0a 20  **a git:// URL..**
00000060  20 4d 61 6b 65 20 73 75 72 65 20 79 6f 75 72 20  **Make sure your**
00000070  63 6f 72 65 2e 67 69 74 50 72 6f 78 79 20 63 6f  **core.gitProxy co**
00000080  6e 66 69 67 20 6f 70 74 69 6f 6e 20 61 6e 64 20  **nfig option and**
00000090  74 68 65 0a 20 20 47 49 54 5f 50 52 4f 58 59 5f  **the.  GIT_PROXY_**
000000a0  43 4f 4d 4d 41 4e 44 20 65 6e 76 69 72 6f 6e 6d  **COMMAND environm**
000000b0  65 6e 74 20 76 61 72 69 61 62 6c 65 20 61 72 65  **ent variable are**
000000c0  20 4e 4f 54 20 73 65 74 2e 0a                    **NOT set..**
Incoming packet #0xa, type 98 / 0x62 (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST)
00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 0b 65 78 69 74 2d 73 74 61  ........**exit-sta**
00000010  74 75 73 00 00 00 00 01                          **tus**.....
Event Log: Started a shell/command
Event Log: Session sent command exit status 1
Event Log: Main session channel closed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub does not offer Subversion access over SSH.  If you want to use a GitHub repository with Subversion, you need to use HTTPS.  Otherwise, you can access the repository as a Git repository with either HTTPS or SSH.

Comment: I was looking for this anywhere on github, but never able to find a definitive statement.